# Determine if a tree is balanced or not in linear time

Tags: c#, tree, graph-theory

The following programme returns whether a tree is balanced or not. A tree is said to be balanced if a path from the root to any leaf has the same length.

```
using System;
namespace BalancedTree
{
public class MainClass 
{
    static bool isBalanced(int[][] sons) 
    {
        return isBalanced(sons, 0);
    }

    static bool isBalanced(int[][] sons, int startNode) 
    {
        int[] children = sons[startNode];

        int minHeight = int.MaxValue;
        int maxHeight = int.MinValue;

        bool allChildBalanced = true;

        if(children.Length == 0)
                return true;
        else 
        {
            foreach (int node in children) 
            {
                int h = height(sons, node);
                if(h > maxHeight)
                    maxHeight = h;

                if(h < minHeight)
                    minHeight = h;  
            }
        }
        foreach (int node in children) 
        {
            allChildBalanced = allChildBalanced && isBalanced(sons, node);

            if(!allChildBalanced)
                return false;
        }
        return Math.Abs(maxHeight - minHeight) < 2 && allChildBalanced;
    }

    static int height(int[][] sons, int startNode) 
    {
        int maxHeight = 0;

        foreach (int child in sons[startNode]) 
        {
            int thisHeight = height(sons, child);
            if(thisHeight > maxHeight) 
                maxHeight = thisHeight;
        }
        return 1 + maxHeight;
    }

    public static void Main (string[] args) 
    {
        int[][] sons = new int[6][];

        sons[0] = new int[] { 1, 2, 4 };
        sons[1] = new int[] { };
        sons[2] = new int[] { 3, 5};
        sons[3] = new int[] { };
        sons[4] = new int[] { };
        sons[5] = new int[] { };

        Console.WriteLine (isBalanced(sons));
    }

}
}
```

My problem is that my code is very inefficient, due to recursive calls to function

```
static int height(int[][] sons, int startNode)
```

making the time complexity exponential. 
I know this can be optimised in case of a binary tree, but I'm looking for a way to optimise my programme in case of a general tree as described above.
One idea would be for instance to call function 'height' from the current node instead of startNode. 
My only constraint is time complexity which must be linear, but I can use additional memory.

Comment: I don't really see the tree, all I see is a jagged 2D array. Which is not a tree structure I'm familiar with. I would expect a structure with a contract like `public interface INode<T>{ T Value { get;set; } INode<T> Parent { get;set; } IEnumerable<INode<T>> ChildNodes { get; } void AddChild(INode<T> childNode); }` or something similar.

Comment: I used an adjacency list `int[][] sons` where node 0 is the root and we define edges that go from the root to the leafs. This representation is tree adjacency list.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I have never done C#. So, there will be no example code.

However, it shouldn't be too hard for you to do it.

Defining isBalanced() recursively will never give best performance. The reason is simple: A tree can still be unbalanced, if all sub-trees are balanced. So, you can't just traverse the tree once.

However, your height() function already does the right thing. It visits every node in the tree only once to find the height (i.e. maximum length from the root to a leaf).

All you have to do is write a minDistance() function that finds the minimum length from the root to a leaf. You can do this using almost the same code.

With these functions a tree is balanced if and only if height(...)==minDistance(...).

Finally, you can merge both function into one that returns a (min,max) pair. This will not change time complexity but could bring down execution time a bit, if returning pairs is not too expensive in C#

Comment: BTW: There are a lot of different definitions of balanced trees out there. I stuck to the one you gave in your question.

Comment: Yes, this could be an idea but it doesn't solve the problem. In fact, I'm looking for a function that would have linear time complexity.

Comment: Your height() function has linear time complexity in terms of nodes. You call height() only once with the root node as parameter. It than runs through all the nodes recursively. During the recursion height() is called once for every node and (added over all these calls) the foreach-body is executed once for every node (except the root node).